# VBA: How do I apply a formula to cells adjacent to non-empty cells?

Tags: vba, excel

`FORMULA = INDEX(Sheet2!$A$2:$A$1000,MATCH(A2,Sheet2!$G$2:$G$1000,0))`

A2 is a cell in active sheet, not sure if I need to be specific and say Sheet1!A2. The output would then be on B2.

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=INDEX(Sheet2!R3C1:R1000C1,MATCH(Sheet1!RC[-4],Sheet2!R3C7:R1000C7,0))"
```

is what I got from record macro but not sure what the RC things are.

> Column A    Formula Column
>
> A
> B
> C
> D
> E
> F
> G
> H
> I

I think I need a for loop to evaluate all cells adjacent to cells that have a value to the left. I'm not sure how to input the formula with referencing cells in another sheet as well as moving down the column.

Comment: i think `INDEX(Sheet1!$A$2:$A$1000..` should be `INDEX(Sheet2!$A$2:$A$1000...`

Comment: you are correct. That is a typo

Comment: If you are putting it in Column B: then `C[-4]` will through error because there is no column 4 columns to the left.  There is only 1.  So the max negative can be -1.

Comment: gotcha. yeah I copy pasted and replaced actual data hence the wrong stuff. in my actual data I have data 4 columns over.

The formula part seems straight forward from macro recording but I just don't know how to apply this so that it runs a loop until the last row with data. Similar to how you double click the lower right corner of a formula cell.

Each time I pull data there might be more or less rows. So sometimes it would need to evaluate until K or if there is less, F.

Comment: So what is the exact final formula you are looking for, not the R1C1, but the actual formula in the cell at the end? Also into what column will it be going?  it would be easier to help if we knew exactly what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. This ended up working for me.

```
'`Sub ApplyFormula()
'
' ApplyFormula Macro
'
Dim i&

For i = 2 To ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
    If Cells(i, 1).Value <> "" Then Cells(i, 6).FormulaR1C1 = "=INDEX(Sheet2!R2C1:R1000C1,MATCH(Sheet1!RC[-4],Sheet2!R2C7:R1000C7,0))"

Next
End Sub
```

Comment: That's Great.  Just an FYI, when using INDEX/MATCH, You can use full column references without detriment; `"=INDEX(Sheet2!C[1],MATCH(Sheet1!RC[-4],Sheet2!C[7],0))"`